# Class mapping Scala, like Orika

Tags: scala, mapping, scala-2.10, orika

Getting started with Scala and hunting around for [Orika](https://code.google.com/p/orika/) modules but for Scala.  It is possible to create custom property builders in Orika but for stuff like case cases with value fields I would need to (with Scala 2.10+) reflex fields (mirroring) for setting immutables.  Assuming there is a native approach with a Scala module?

Answer (score 0):

I know `Orika` has lot more features but, if you just want to create a copy of an instance to a new instance and change some attributes of the new instance, scala has inbuilt feature for it. Use `case classes` and you can use `copy` method on it to create new instances.

```
case class Bird(name: String, color: String)

scala> val chicken = Bird("twitty", "yellow")
chicken: Bird = Bird(twitty,yellow)

scala> val coq = chicken.copy(color = "red")
coq: Bird = Bird(twitty,red)
```

Comment: Thanks but looking for something a bit richer beyond just case classes.  Plus being about to break apart one class into a set other classes.